# Jquery Tooltips Edit

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I always wanted a page where user can leave comment to me in tooltip. after much seraching i wasnt able to locate one suiting my need.
I learnt this can be done in Language Jquery. I made a tool tip after learning on website but how can i enable "double click on tool-tip" to edit a and save that data via ajax, Is there any one available.

I want to be able to hover on a div to generate a tooltip which should display some text and on double click of that text it changes to text editor(an input box)

[here is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/8L9du/) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is called "Edit In Place". Take a look at the [Jeditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Also, jQuery is not a language. JavaScript (aka ECMAScript) is the language. jQuery is a library for JavaScript.